# Using growisofs & add title to burned cd

Tags: command-line, burning

I want to burn a CD and/or DVD with this command:

```
growisofs -Z /dev/sr0 -r -J /path/to/files
```

but it doesn't add a name or title to the CD/DVD burned. I want to add a 'Backup 01' title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are after the `-V` option. For your example try this:

```
growisofs -Z /dev/sr0 -r -J -V "Backup 01" /path/to/files
```

You are allowed 32 characters for this volume ID...

**References:**

- [Andrews Corner: Backing up Some Directories to DVD](http://www.andrews-corner.org/burning.html#backup)